# length and length() in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string

Why do we have the length of an array as an attribute, `array.length`, and for String we have a method, `str.length()`?

Is there some reason?

Comment: Has been discussed before at CodeRanch. See the discussion [here.](http://www.coderanch.com/t/383558/Java-General/java/String-length-vs-Arrays-length)

Answer (score 109):

Let me first highlight three different ways for similar purpose.

`length` -- **arrays** (`int[]`, `double[]`, `String[]`) -- to know the length of the arrays

`length()` -- **String related Object** (`String`, `StringBuilder`, etc) -- to know the length of the String

`size()` --  **Collection Object** (`ArrayList`, `Set`, etc) -- to know the size of the Collection

Now forget about `length()` consider just `length` and `size()`.

`length` is not a method, so it completely makes sense that it will not work on objects. It only works on arrays.
`size()` its name describes it better and as it is a method, it will be used in the case of those objects who work with collection (collection frameworks) as I said up there.

Now come to **`length()`**:
String is not a primitive array (so we can't use `.length`) and also not a Collection (so we cant use `.size()`) that's why we also need a different one which is `length()` (keep the differences and serve the purpose).

As answer to **Why?**
I find it useful, easy to remember and use and friendly.

Answer (score 27):

A bit simplified you can think of it as arrays being a special case and not ordinary classes (a bit like primitives, but not). String and all the collections are classes, hence the methods to get size, length or similar things.

I guess the reason at the time of the design was performance. If they created it today they had probably come up with something like array-backed collection classes instead.

If anyone is interested, here is a small snippet of code to illustrate the difference between the two in generated code, first the source:

```
public class LengthTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {12,1,4};
    String string = "Hoo";
    System.out.println(array.length);
    System.out.println(string.length());
  }
}
```

Cutting a way the not so important part of the byte code, running `javap -c` on the class results in the following for the two last lines:

```
20: getstatic   #3; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
23: aload_1
24: arraylength
25: invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
28: getstatic   #3; //Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
31: aload_2
32: invokevirtual   #5; //Method java/lang/String.length:()I
35: invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
```

In the first case (20-25) the code just asks the JVM for the size of the array (in JNI this would have been a call to GetArrayLength()) whereas in the String case (28-35) it needs to do a method call to get the length.

In the mid 1990s, without good JITs and stuff, it would have killed performance totally to only have the java.util.Vector (or something similar) and not a language construct which didn't really behave like a class but was fast. They could of course have masked the property as a method call and handled it in the compiler but I think it would have been even more confusing to have a method on something that isn't a real class.

Comment: Java treats array as objects and strings as an immutable objects!! :|

Comment: @Myth: I don't see your point... The length property of arrays is not a public field or anything, it is a construct of the jvm (arraylength is even an operation in the bytecode). It is very obvious when you do JNI or if you just disassemble the code where it comes from.

Comment: I don’t think that the reasoning of the original design was performance only. How would you implement `Vector` when the Java language had no array support?

Answer (score 9):

Consider:

```
int[] myArray = new int[10];
String myString = "hello world!";
List<int> myList = new ArrayList<int>();

myArray.length    // Gives the length of the array
myString.length() // Gives the length of the string
myList.size()     // Gives the length of the list
```

It's very likely that strings and arrays were designed at different times and hence ended up using different conventions. One justification is that since Strings use arrays internally, a method, `length()`, was used to avoid duplication of the same information. Another is that using a method `length()` helps emphasize the immutability of strings, even though the size of an array is also unchangeable.

Ultimately this is just an inconsistency that evolved that would definitely be fixed if the language were ever redesigned from the ground up. As far as I know no other languages (C#, Python, Scala, etc.) do the same thing, so this is likely just a slight flaw that ended up as part of the language.

You'll get an error if you use the wrong one anyway.

Comment: This is more justifiable and unbiased answer.

Answer (score 7):

**`.length`** is a one-off property of Java. It's used to find the size of a single dimensional **array**.

**`.length()`** is a method. It's used to find the length of a **`String`**. It avoids duplicating the value.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, an Array stores its length separately from the structure that actually holds the data. When you create an Array, you specify its length, and that becomes a defining attribute of the Array. No matter what you do to an Array of length N (change values, null things out, etc.), it will always be an Array of length N.

A String's length is incidental; it is not an attribute of the String, but a byproduct. Though  Java Strings are in fact immutable, if it were possible to change their contents, you could change their length. Knocking off the last character (if it were possible) would lower the length.

I understand this is a fine distinction, and I may get voted down for it, but it's true. If I make an Array of length 4, that length of four is a defining characteristic of the Array, and is true regardless of what is held within. If I make a String that contains "dogs", that String is length 4 because it happens to contain four characters.

I see this as justification for doing one with an attribute and the other with a method. In truth, it may just be an unintentional inconsistency, but it's always made sense to me, and this is always how I've thought about it.

Answer (score 2):

I was taught that for arrays, length is not retrieved through a method due to the following fear: programmers would just assign the length to a local variable before entering a loop (think a for loop where the conditional uses the array's length.) The programmer would supposedly do so to trim down on function calls (and thereby improve performance.) The problem is that the length might change during the loop, and the variable wouldn't.

Comment: The length of an array can not change during the loop.

Comment: you can't change the length of this particular array, but you can assign a new one to the same variable

Comment: @Bozho: True, but then it is another array and if you do that intentionally and don't update whatever you check your loop against you have a bug. Java has never had the intention to stop you from writing bugs. You can do infinite loops, recursion til you die and all kinds of logical errors without java trying to stop you from it. It is a good reason for not storing the length in a variable but it sure isn't the reason why it is designed that way.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever an array is created, its size is specified. So length can be considered as a construction attribute. For String, it essentially a char array. Length is a property of the char array. There is no need to put length as a field, because not everything needs this field.
http://www.programcreek.com/2013/11/start-from-length-length-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add some remarks to the great [answer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#Java) by [Fredrik](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1).

The [Java Language Specification in Section 4.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.3.1) states

> An *object* is a *class instance* or an *array*.

So array has indeed a very special role in Java. I do wonder why.

One could argue that current implementation array is/was important for a better performance. But than it is an internal structure, which should not be exposed.

> They could of course have masked the property as a method call and handled it in the compiler but I think it would have been even more confusing to have a method on something that isn't a real class.

I agree with Fredrik, that a smart compiler optimazation would have been the better choice. This would also solve the problem, that even if you use a property for arrays, you have not solved the problem for strings and other (immutable) collection types, because, e.g., `string` is based on a `char` array as you can see on the class definition of `String`:

```
public final class String implements java.io.Serializable, Comparable<String>, CharSequence {           
    private final char value[]; // ...
```

And I do not agree with that it would be even more confusing, because array does inherit [all methods from `java.lang.Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

As an engineer I really do not like the answer "Because it has been always this way." and wished there would be a better answer. But in this case it seems to be.

**tl;dr**

In my opinion, it is a design flaw of Java and should not have implemented this way.