# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5

Tags: android, kotlin

> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=5; index=5
>           at com.example.android.architecture.MainActivity.updateDisplay(MainActivity.kt:59)
>           at com.example.android.architecture.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:44)

changing the index 
and class view

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var dice: IntArray
    private lateinit var headlineText: String

    private val imageViews by lazy {
        arrayOf<ImageView>(findViewById(R.id.die1),
        findViewById(R.id.die1),
        findViewById(R.id.die2),
        findViewById(R.id.die3),
        findViewById(R.id.die4),
            findViewById(R.id.die5)
        )
    }
        private val headline by lazy { findViewById<TextView>(R.id.headline) }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        headlineText = savedInstanceState?.getString(HEADLINE_TEXT)
            ?: getString(R.string.welcome)
        dice = savedInstanceState?.getIntArray(DICE_COLLECTION)
            ?: intArrayOf(6,6,6,6,6)

        lifecycle.addObserver(MyLifeCycleObserver())

        fab.setOnClickListener{
            fabClickHandler()}

        updateDisplay()

    }


    private fun fabClickHandler(){
        dice = DiceHelper.rollDice()
        headlineText = DiceHelper.evaluateDice(this,dice)
        updateDisplay()

    }

    private fun updateDisplay() {
        for (i in 0 until imageViews.size) {

            val drawableId = when (dice[i]) {
                1 -> R.drawable.die_1
                2 -> R.drawable.die_2
                3 -> R.drawable.die_3
                4 -> R.drawable.die_4
                5 -> R.drawable.die_5
                6 -> R.drawable.die_6
                else -> R.drawable.die_6
            }
            imageViews[i].setImageResource(drawableId)
        }
        headline.text = headlineText
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
        outState?.putString(HEADLINE_TEXT,headlineText)
        outState?.putIntArray(DICE_COLLECTION,dice)
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }
}
```

Unsure why my android application isn't running

Comment: Could you mark the line number 59 and 44 with a comment where you are getting the exception?

Comment: `dice` only has 5 elements, `imageViews` probably more (and that is not (pure) java!!)

Comment: that's not java @CarlosHeuberger, the tag should be removed, you're right

Comment: @a_local_nobody but that should have been the OP's duty....(only the Java tag was there when my first comment was written)

Comment: no I agree, not saying you are wrong, actually just confirming with you that it is not java :) @CarlosHeuberger

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 1):

dice is of size 5 where  while ImageViews has 6 elements so the loop run 6 times and in the sixth iteration Exception occurs

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing your dice array with five elements in case of null savedinstance

```
"dice = savedInstanceState?.getIntArray(DICE_COLLECTION)
    ?: intArrayOf(6,6,6,6,6)"'
```

===========================================================
And your Imageviews Array has 6 elements

```
private val imageViews by lazy {
        arrayOf<ImageView>(findViewById(R.id.die1),
        findViewById(R.id.die1),
        findViewById(R.id.die2),
        findViewById(R.id.die3),
        findViewById(R.id.die4),
            findViewById(R.id.die5)
        )
    }
```

=====================================================
so while you are accessing dice elements in loop running

```
for (i in 0 until imageViews.size) {
            val drawableId = when (dice[i]) {
```

It give exception

Answer (score 0):

The error is here:

```
for (i in 0 until imageViews.size) {
            val drawableId = when (dice[i]) {
```

`imageViews` has 6 elements.
`dice` has 5 elements.

```
dice = savedInstanceState?.getIntArray(DICE_COLLECTION)
            ?: intArrayOf(6,6,6,6,6)

private val imageViews by lazy {
        arrayOf<ImageView>(
          findViewById(R.id.die1),  
          findViewById(R.id.die1),  //maybe it is duplicated
          findViewById(R.id.die2),
          findViewById(R.id.die3),
          findViewById(R.id.die4),
          findViewById(R.id.die5)
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Length** is constant which is used to find out the array storing capacity not the number of elements in the array.

Number of elements in the array is called **size**.

*If you use array with **5 elements**, your last element must have **index** 4. Because all arrays start from index 0.*

[Difference between size and lenght](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20192843/difference-between-size-and-length-methods)