# processing/java: cannot invoke length() on the array type boolean[]

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

Surprised that this wasn't already posted. I'm making a for loop, and its worked before but for some reason I can't find the length of a `boolean` array.

```
for(int z = 0; z < keyIsFound.length(); z++){
  //do something
}
```

Comment: `keyIsFound.length` - no ()

Comment: You should visit this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965500/length-and-length-in-java) for more information.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For arrays, their lengths are fixed when we create them.
If you want to get the length of any array, use `.length`.

Answer (score 5):

.length = to get the length for arrays 
.length() = to get the length of Strings

Answer (score 3):

For array the `length` is a property - not a method. You have to write `keyIsFound.length`. Array is a fixed sized data structure when you create an array like -

```
int[] nums = new int[10];
```

You actually fixed it `length` too.

Answer (score 0):

`length` is a field, not a method.

Use something like `for (int z = 0; keyIsFound != null && z < keyIsFound.length; ++z){` instead: i.e. drop the parentheses. Note my `null` check, which you should *consider* incorporating either with the `for` loop, or, better still, in a containing `if`.

(I like to use `++z` rather than `z++` as I'm an old-fashioned cat).

Comment: I'd think it would be enough to check for `keyIsFound != null` at the very start, in a separate `if` clause.

Comment: Very true, I could play the "compiler will optimise out card", but then I open myself to ridicule over using ++z.