# args.length() is showing compilation error where as args.length is working fine in command line argument

Tags: java

If I do `args.length();` it is showing compilation error where as args.length is working fine.

but if it is not command line argument for eg. `String str = "hello";`
in this `str.length` is not working but `str.length()` is working fine.

please help!

Comment: [length vs length() in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965500/length-and-length-in-java)

Comment: `.length()` for strings, `.length` for arrays.

Comment: It is often useful to include the compilation error in your post.  I recommend that any new programmer take the tie to read the message of an exception when it is encountered as it will not only help when requesting advice, but will certainly aid you in identifying the cause of the exception.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you refer to the `args` parameter of a `main` method, that's because arrays do not provide a `length()` method like `String`s, but a `length` `public` property, returning `int`.

See docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Answer (score 1):

`String` as an **object** has a built in method called `length()`

`Array` as an **object** does not have a built in method `length()`, but it has a property called `length`

Answer (score 0):

The parameter arg of the main method is an **Array**.

Arrays have a public **property** `length` unlike `Collections` or `Strings` that have `length()` **method**

Comment: actually started learning java today only.
so u means String args [] is an array of strings and length is a method for  array?

Comment: It not a method but an instance variable which is `public` and `final`.

Comment: No, Arrays like `String [] args` don't have a `length()` method they have a **public property** where they store length. We acces public property like this : `args.length`. Java have another enhanced type of arrays called Collections like List ant Set they have a `length()` **method** like Strings

Comment: @AniketThakur would you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

> The `public` `final` field `length`, which contains the number of components of the array. length may be positive or zero.

There is no `length()` method. [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html).

`String` class has a method called `length()` ([Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html))