# How .length of int[] works in java?

Tags: java, performance, jvm

I've a code something similar to this.

```
public static final int[] VALUES = {1,2,3,4,5,6};

for(int i=0; i< VALUES.length; i++) {
    //Do something
}
```

Is it good to have `VALUES.length` as part of loop. Should I assign it to a variable and use it here?

In case of String array, I've seen it's been doing this way.

```
public static final String[] STR_VALUES = {"apple", "orange", "butterfly"};

int length = STR_VALUES.length();
for(int i=0; i< VALUES.length; i++) {
        //Do something
}
```

Since it's a performance optimization that we need not compute the length again and again. But in the case of int[] it looks like I'm using instance variable of a class. But these are primitives where does class coming into picture here? I'm getting confused.

How this is process? From where Do we get the value from? How can I see it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8781022/is-an-array-an-object-in-java

Comment: Yes, it is good style to have `VALUES.length` as part of the loop. IMHO putting it into a variable first (as in your second snippet) just overcomplicates things. Whether we’re talking primitives or object references makes no difference to the question.

Comment: In your second example it should also be just `STR_VALUES.length` without the round brackets, there’s no difference.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1965506/217324) on the duplicate target describes where arraylength comes from.

Comment: @OleV.V. the second variant has even more issues, like attempting to declare an `int[]` array containing strings. And, of course, there’s no difference, as the OP’s second loop still uses `STR_VALUES.length` in the loop, instead of the new local variable. Note that you don’t have to declare the variable outside, you can use, e.g. `for(int i=0, len=VALUES.length; i<len; i++) { … }`, but considering that you get everything for free, when just using `for(String value: STR_VALUES) …`, including the things not considered here, it’s indeed not worth thinking about it…

Comment: @Holger thanks for pointing it out. Actually I thought String[] but wrote it as int[] my bad ! :-(